# Finding Java 8 with a Mac app

Tags: java, macos

I have an app with a few thousand user downloads, written in Java, that's been stable for years. It runs on Windows and OSX. Now there are problems with the new release of OSX High Sierra.

The app crashes with Java 1.6, but appears to run fine with Java 1.8.

Inside the app folder is a file `Info.plist`.  That file originally specified a Java `JVMVersion` of 1.5+.  This causes my app to be run under Java 1.6.  If Java 1.6 is not present, a message pops up prompting the user to install the "Legacy Java SE6 Runtime."  I've tried updating `Info.plist` to specify 1.8+, but when I try to run the app a message pops saying, "No compatible version of Java 1.8+ is available."  This is even though I've directly downloaded and installed Java 8 Version 151 directly from Oracle.com.

How can I get the app to run under Java 8?

Comment: Have you considered bundling the JRE?

Comment: Is the $JAVA_HOME environment variable set to point to the java8 jre you've downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is to bundle the JRE.  It's been an adventure getting everything to to work.  For others that have to go through the same or a similar process, I'm listing the steps.

My app is written in Java,  My main development machine is Windows.  To distribute the app I need to copy the necessary files to my Mac and package them there.

Download `apache-ant-1.10.1-bin.zip` from `ant.apache.org`.  Move it to `/Library/Java/Extensions`.

```
% sudo nano /etc/paths # add /Library/Java/Extensions/apache-ant-1.10.1/bin
% nano .bash_profile # add ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME
```

Download appbundler from https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/, and install it in `~/JCode/appbundler`.

```
% cd ~/JCode/appbundler
% ant
```

This creates `~/JCode/appbundler/bin/appbundler-1.0ea.jar`.  Copy it to `~/JCode/intonia/lib`.

On Windows, use Eclipse and Proguard to create `Intonia.jar`, and copy to `~/JCode/intonia`.  Also copy other library jars and files needed for the distribution.

Create build.xml in `~/JCode/intonia`.  Here is my build.xml:

```
<project name="Intonia" default="bundle-Intonia" basedir=".">        
<!-- Import environment variables -->
<property environment="env"/>

<taskdef name="bundleapp"
     classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
     classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0ea.jar" />

<target name="bundle-Intonia">
    <delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="appBundle"
    name="Intonia"
    displayname="Intonia"
    identifier="com.intonia.Intonia"
    icon="Intonia.icns"
    mainclassname="com.intonia.tony.Intonia">
    <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
    <classpath file="Intonia.jar"/>
    <classpath file="jh.jar"/>
    <classpath file="jl1.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpath file="mp3spi1.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpath file="tritonus_share.jar"/>
    <classpath file="DefaultOptions.tab"/>
    <option value="-Xdock:icon=Intonia.icns"/>
    </bundleapp>
</target>
</project>
```

Notable tweaks to get things to run properly include  `<runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>`, and `<option value="-Xdock:icon=Intonia.icns"/>` in addition to `icon="Intonia.icns"`.

```
% cd ~/JCode/intonia
% ant
```

This creates `~/JCode/intonia/appBundle/Intonia.app`.

My app uses JavaHelp.  JavaHelp requires that the help files be in a subdirectory of the jar file called `Help`.  I haven't found a way to get appbundler to create and populate this directory, so I have to add it manually.  In the Finder, Show Package contents.  Option-drag folder `~/JCode/intonia/Help` into the `Contents/Java/` directory of the `Intonia.app`.

```
% codesign -s "Developer ID Application" -fv --deep appBundle/Intonia.app
% pkgbuild --root appBundle Intonia.pkg
```

Create a 'Distribution.xml' in `~/JCode/intonia`.  Here's the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="2">
<title>Intonia</title>
<options customize="never" rootVolumeOnly="true"/>
<conclusion file="Welcome.rtf" mime-type="application/rtf"/>
<license file="EULA.txt" mime-type="text/plain"/>
<allowed-os-versions>
    <os-version min="10.6.6" />
</allowed-os-versions>
<options customize="never" require-scripts="false"/>
<product id="intonia" version="1.4.0" />
<choices-outline>
    <line choice="default">
    <line choice="intonia"/>
    </line>
</choices-outline>
<choice id="default"/>
<choice id="intonia" visible="false">
    <pkg-ref id="intonia"/>
</choice>
<pkg-ref id="intonia" version="1.4.0" onConclusion="none">Intonia.pkg</pkg-ref>
</installer-gui-script>
```

Lastly, run productbuild.  It can sign the distribution

```
% productbuild --distribution Distribution.xml --sign "Developer ID Installer" --resources . InstallIntonia1.4.0.pkg
```